# Error to Run the server (POSTGRESQL + AWS)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-rds, strapi

I have an app from **Strapi** that was made for other developers.
Now I'm starting this work so I need to set up everything.
I can only run the server when I use local **DB - PostgreSQL**- on staging side.
When I go to production side, with my local DB, the **strapi** is basically empty.
So I was trying to connect with the DB from **PostgresSQL - AWS** - direct.
Then I put everything on the `.env` file as they sent me.
But when I try to run the server (npm run develop)
there is this error:

`(node:26421) Warning:` S3 configuration options passed at root level of the plugin's providerOptions is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please wrap them inside the `s3Options:{}` property.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 10.0.2.82:5432
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1187:16) {
  errno: -61,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '10.0.2.82',
  port: 5432
}
```

I really don’t know how to fix it and I'm very afraid of doing something wrong with the DB.
I appreciate any help!! Thanks.

I already did npm install, npm update.